# Condition on finding a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, test

I'm trying to write a script which looks for a file and if it is found, saves the full path to a variable. Current version:

```
if [[ -n FOUND_PATH=$(find "$PATH" -name "file.exe") ]]; then
    echo "Found, full path: "$FOUND_PATH
else
    echo "Not found."
fi
```

Evaluates the `[[ -n ]]` expression as true even if no file is actually found and `FOUND_PATH` is actually empty. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

To illustrate the problem I'm currently having, this code:

```
find "$PATH" -name "file.exe"

FOUND_PATH=$(find "$PATH" -name "file.exe")

if [[ -n "$(FOUND_PATH)" ]]; then
    echo "Found, full path: "$FOUND_PATH
else
    echo "Not found."
fi
```

Returns just `Found, full path:`, so the first line outputs nothing at all, but when checking it later for being non-empty string in the third line, it evaluates as non-empty!

Comment: The `$PATH` variable is your shell's executable search path; you should probably pick a different variable name so you won't interfere with it.

Comment: Right, it's not what I'm actually using on my system, it's a replacement I use here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignment  doesn't give some result  in bash like it would in e.g. C. You have to do:

```
FOUND_PATH=$(find "$PATH" -name "file.exe")
if [[ -n "$FOUND_PATH" ]]; then
    echo "Found, full path: $FOUND_PATH"
else
    echo "Not found."
fi
```

and make sure your $FOUND_PATH is between double quotes, in the parameter to the first `echo` too.

If your $PATH is not a single directory but e.g. `/usr/bin:/bin` you might want to change the first line into:

```
FOUND_PATH=$(find $(echo "$PATH" | sed "s/:/ /g" ) -name "file.exe")
```

Comment: This hasn't really solved the problem, I still get this output: `Found, full path:`

Comment: That is probably because your $PATH is not a single directory. How is yours defined in the this script? You best just start with making sure `fine "$PATH" -name "file.exe"` works for you.

Comment: `PATH="/cygdrive/c/program files (x86)/some folder/"`, `find "$PATH" -name "file.exe"` returns nothing as expected.

Comment: It returns "nothing, as expected" or "nothing as I expected" ?

Comment: "nothing, as expected", since there is no such file at that directory.